# Set values of a column to NA after a given point

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID   NUMBER   X
1      5      2
1      3      4
1      6      3
1      2      5
2      7      3
2      3      5
2      9      3
2      4      2
```

and I'd like to set values of variable X to NA after the variable NUMBER increses (even though after it decreases again) for each ID, and obtaining:

```
ID   NUMBER   X
1     5       2
1     3       4
1     6       NA
1     2       NA
2     7       3
2     3       5
2     9       NA
2     4       NA
```

How can I do it?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the criteria do you need to set NA ? Is it when NUMBER > 6 ? Or depdending on the row number ? Or the two last row of each group of identical IDs ?

Comment: After the variable NUMBER increases (even though after it decreases again).

Comment: Like, in the 3rd r, NUMBER is equal to 6 and in the 2nd it was equal to 3; so the variable NUMBER increased. After that point I want variable X equal to NA, for that ID.

Answer (score 1):

Surely not the most elegant solution, but it is quite intuitive:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, n := ifelse(NUMBER > shift(NUMBER, 1, "lag"),1,0), by=ID]
d[is.na(n), n := 0]
d[, n := cumsum(n), by=ID]
d[n>0, X := NA ]
d

   ID NUMBER  X n
1:  1      5  2 0
2:  1      3  4 0
3:  1      6 NA 1
4:  1      2 NA 1
5:  2      7  3 0
6:  2      3  5 0
7:  2      9 NA 1
8:  2      4 NA 1
```

Comment: Another option is `set(DT, DT[, .I[c(0L, cumsum(diff(X) < 0L)) > 0L], ID]$V1, "X", NA_integer_)`. btw `data.table` has a fast version of `ifelse` (i.e. `fifelse`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dplyr` package. If your dataframe is called df then you can use this code:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate ( X = c(X[1:(min(which(diff(Number) > 0)))],rep("NA",length(X)-(min(which(diff(Number) > 0)))))) %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

I first grouped them with ID and then I found the first increasing number with `diff` and `which`.